# Issue with div width

Tags: html, css

I have two divs displayed inline, each div has a width of 50%.
Below these two divs, there is a 100% width div.

Here's my code

```
<div class="col_1_2"></div>
<div class="full-description">description</div>
<div class="col_1_2"></div>
<div class="full-description">description</div>

.col_1_2 {
   float:left;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width:50%;
 }

.full-description {
   width: 100%;
}
```

The div called 'full-description' is not perfectly displayed below the ".col_1_2".

What I want

[image]

Thanks for the help !

Comment: What is your current output? Please post the Jsfiddle link.

Comment: You would probably have to change the structure to achieve that layout using floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably have to change the structure to achieve that layout using floats.

...and don't forget to clear the floats.

```css
.col_1_2 {
   float:left;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width:50%;
    height: 100px;
    background: lightblue;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border:1px solid grey;
 }

.full-description {
    height: 50px;
    background: grey;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    clear:both;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="col_1_2"></div>
<div class="col_1_2"></div>
<div class="full-description">description</div>
<div class="full-description">description</div>

<div class="col_1_2"></div>
<div class="col_1_2"></div>
<div class="full-description">description</div>
<div class="full-description">description</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the line break after the DIV's. They are interpreted as spaces, so you want to avoid these. Try something like this

```
<div class="col_1_2"></div><?php
?><div class="full-description">description</div><?php
?><div class="col_1_2"></div><?php
?><div class="full-description">description</div>
```

*In your preferred language, of course*

Answer (score 0):

add this after every row

```
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
```

then style to this

```
      .clearfix {
            clear:both;

         }
```

and also float this one

```
     .full-description {
       float:left;
       width:100%;
       }
```

hope this will work